# When do you get a "User was removed" message in your reputation tab, accompanied by a -2?

Tags: support, reputation

I'm asking about when you get a *User was removed* message in your reputation tab, accompanied by a *-2*.

Besides the case where the user upvoted a few and downvoted many posts, is there any other situation where a net loss of two rep results from a user being removed?

Will the two rep gained from accepting an answer be reversed if the answer we accepted was from the now deleted user?

If a user accepted an edit from another user (resulting in the editor gaining two rep), will the rep be reversed when the user who accepted was removed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's likely to be a suggested edit of yours, for which the removed user was the final approver. That is recorded as a vote, and most votes are deleted when a user is deleted, that's why you lose the 2 reputation. If you accept an answer, that's *your* vote, so it won't be deleted.

You can check which post the affected suggested edit was made on with a trick I described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312191/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange.